# How can I read a running Swing GUI´s TextField or Cell values from external unrelated code?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency, jvm

It has to be someway to access it. Indeed I never doing with any kind of program. I imagine they are two instances of the JVM and so must be conflictive..

For instance, reading rows from a JTable which is already running on another Java app. Id like to test programatically the results that are appearing there, running myTest app one Swing app is running

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to do. What do you mean by external, unrelated code? Could you edit your question and give us more information on what you want to achieve

Comment: @Sujay: I'm guessing that he's trying to create or find something like Spy++ for Java's Swing that is able to monitor the state of a Swing GUI running on an unrelated JVM.

Comment: Googling "Java Swing spy utilities" showed this hit: [JSpy](http://code.google.com/p/robotframework-javatools/wiki/JSpy). I've never used it and so cannot vouch for its effectiveness or safety.

Comment: JSpy says that is a GUI debugger by mouse hoverin, not programatically.

Comment: Yes, but perhaps by inspecting the source, you'll be able to get some ideas.

Comment: As a last option Ill do, Im researhing any high level way of doing it. I am trying right now FEST, but the documentation seems to me very hard to follow, althought I already managed to read some components

Comment: This is the approach im following right now. If it succeeds I will answer my own question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674383/fest-wait-for-the-gui-to-load-before-doing-anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using FEST: http://fest.easytesting.org/

It can be used to simulate all imaginable human actions over the running swing app as well