# FEST: Wait for the GUI to load before doing anything

Tags: java, swing, testing, awtrobot, fest

```
    @Before public void setUp() {
        Robot robot = BasicRobot.robotWithCurrentAwtHierarchy();
        ApplicationLauncher.application("myApp").start(); 

        Pause.pause(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        frame = WindowFinder.findFrame("frame0").using(robot);

        JTableFixture table = frame.table(new GenericTypeMatcher<JTable>(JTable.class) {
             @Override protected boolean isMatching(JTable table) {
                return (table instanceof myTreeTable); 
             }  
        });
    }
```

This code works well. If we remove the 5 seconds pause, then the table is not found because it takes some seconds to the app to load it.

I would like to know if there is a cleaner way of doing it. I tried with robot.waitForIdle() after ApplicationLauncher (I guess once EDT is empty, everything is loaded), but it just doesn´t work.

I know pause can use some conditions as an event on when to stop, but I don´t understand how to write it since JavaDoc and official doc is poor.

- Pause.pause(WaitForComponentToShowCondition.untilIsShowing(frame.component())) : I need a component, if I pass the wrapper frame it does not work. And I cannot pass the table because thats precisely what I am waiting for to get.
- I understand then I should probably work with ComponentFoundCondition but I dont get it! I tired with:

  ```
         ComponentMatcher matcher = new GenericTypeMatcher<JTable>(JTable.class) {
             @Override protected boolean isMatching(JTable table) {
               return (table instanceof myTreeTable); 
             }  
         };

         Pause.pause(new ComponentFoundCondition("DebugMsg", frame.robot.finder(), matcher));
  ```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ComponentFinder](http://fest.easytesting.org/swing/apidocs/org/fest/swing/core/ComponentFinder.html) to locate the component. For example, based on the matcher in the question:

```
final ComponentMatcher matcher = new TypeMatcher(myTreeTable.class);

Pause.pause(new Condition("Waiting for myTreeTable") {
    @Override
    public boolean test() {
        Collection<Component> list = 
                window.robot.finder().findAll(window.target, matcher);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }
 }, 5000);
```

Here is an alternative with lookup by name:

```
final ComponentMatcher nameMatcher = new ComponentMatcher(){
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Component c) {
        return "ComponentName".equals(c.getName()) && c.isShowing();
    }
};

Pause.pause(new Condition("Waiting") {
    @Override
    public boolean test() {
        Collection<Component> list = 
                window.robot.finder().findAll(window.target, nameMatcher);
        return list.size() > 0;
    }
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: The curious thing is there is an already existent Condition subclass for this goal, ComponentFoundCondition. So the first part of your answer should be equal to Pause.pause(new ComponentFoundCondition("Waiting formyTreeTable to load...", frame.robot.finder(), matcher, frame.target), 50000); but it seems the condition is never satisfied and u end up with timeout

Comment: OK I found the problem. founding more than one occurrences is considered the same as none, a fail. That means if you are sure there is only one myTreeTable, you can use a match better Pause.pause(new ComponentFoundCondition("Waiting formyTreeTable to load...", frame.robot.finder(), matcher, frame.target), 50000); if not, its better to inherit the Condition as you did, and put size() >0 so size()=2 its valid

Comment: One question: I assume this code has to run in the EDT, since accessing the components is generally not thread safe, right? So if we use this in test code we have to wrap the access in a `GuiQuery`?

Comment: @nikow I assume that finder is executing its methods on EDT. If that is true then there is no need to wrap these actions. Unfortunately I don't have the environment handy to test that assumption. There is also `EdtSafeCondition` that may be helpful.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, I found that `ComponentMatcher` is annotated with @RunsInEDT. Thanks.